# How can I fix this code to spawn multiple types of enemies on the same point with the Corona SdDK?

Tags: lua, corona-sdk

I have this code to spawn a simple enemy outside the window:

```
local function spawnGrupo1()
  local color01 = display.newImage("assets/img/enemigos/blue.png")
  color01.x = 40
  color01.y = -50
  physics.addBody( color01,{density = 5.0, friction = 0.0, bounce = 0} )
end

timer.performWithDelay( 1000, spawnGrupo1, 0)
```

But I want to be able to spawn multiple enemies from that point, and I can't figure it out.

I tried this, but it doesn't work:

```
local function spawnGrupo1()
  local numero = math.random(1, 3)

  if numero == 1 then
    local color01 = display.newImage("assets/img/enemigos/blue.png")
  end
  if numero == 2 then
    local color01 = display.newImage("assets/img/enemigos/yellow.png")
  end
  if numero == 3 then
    local color01 = display.newImage("assets/img/enemigos/red.png")
  end
  color01.x = 40
  color01.y = -50
  physics.addBody( color01,{density = 5.0, friction = 0.0, bounce = 0} )
end

timer.performWithDelay( 1000, spawnGrupo1, 0)
```

How can I approach the problem?

Comment: Can't you take `local color01` out of the scope of the `if`s? E.g. by declaring it just after `local numero `?

Comment: You probably should tell how or why 'it does not work'...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*I'm assuming you have issues with the scope of the variable since you simply say 'It doesn't work'.*

I'm not familiar with Lua, but I'd go with something like this:

```
local function spawnGrupo1()
  local numero = math.random(1, 3)
  local color01

  if numero == 1 then
    color01 = display.newImage("assets/img/enemigos/blue.png")
  end
  if numero == 2 then
    color01 = display.newImage("assets/img/enemigos/yellow.png")
  end
  if numero == 3 then
    color01 = display.newImage("assets/img/enemigos/red.png")
  end

  color01.x = 40
  color01.y = -50
  physics.addBody( color01,{density = 5.0, friction = 0.0, bounce = 0} )
end

timer.performWithDelay( 1000, spawnGrupo1, 0)
```

In your implementation, each `color01` is local the the `if` bloc. By declaring it outside of the `if` blocs like it's been done above, you make sure that it is the same variable that will be used in the `addBody` function call.

You can read a bit more about the concept of scope in lua [here](http://lua-users.org/wiki/ScopeTutorial).